# What is the proper way to invoke a closure action inside a component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I pass a closure action into my component like so:

```
{{deployment-timeline loadMoreDeployments=(action "loadMoreDeployments")}}
```

How should I invoke this in my component?

```
actions:{
  loadMoreDeployments(){
    // which one of the following three invocations is best?
    this.attrs.loadMoreDeployments();
    this.get('loadMoreDeployments')();
    this.loadMoreDeployments();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
this.get('loadMoreDeployments')();
```

or

```
import {get} from '@ember/object';
...
get(this, 'loadMoreDeployments')();
```

The use of `attrs` was never probably introduced, and accessing a property on an ember object with dot notation is not recommended.

Edit: [With ember `3.1` (currently in beta) we will get support for dot notation for getters (no setters yet, and not for proxy objects).](https://emberjs.com/blog/2018/02/16/ember-3-1-beta-released.html) This means that from ember `3.1` on you can safely use:

```
this.loadMoreDeployments();
```

Comment: I 'get' the new syntax - but we're going to lose more adoption over this. : (

Comment: That _IS_ cool... but it's also a _3rd way_ - with exceptions.